Gatus IU title and logo change with docker
I’m using Gatus (https://github.com/TwiN/gatus?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) to monitor the health of various endpoints in my application, and I’d like to customize the title displayed on the Gatus web interface.
I have tried adding the below in my config.yaml file:
ui:
title: Testing Monitoring Dashboards
However the above doesn't work. Any ideas how we can change that and the logo with gatus?
ui:
title: Testing Monitoring Dashboards
The above didn't work whena appended in the config file.

ui: title: is the tab title, just changed to ui.header and it worked.
